# Spring Integration - Outbound Gateway - Chaining

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I have a FileUpload Event that should be sent over to a http:outbound upload URL. In order to do this I have to first authenticate login URL and get the response and set the session id for outbound upload URL to execute. In my case, I have an event listener which listens for the application to publish the event of File Upload. Once it is published my listener can pick up and execute the flow. I am trying to see how this can be implemented because File Upload object would need to persisted until the Login response comes back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose we suggest a `Header Enricher` pattern. So, you place that "FileUpload Event" object into some header and restore it back to the payload when you get that session id response.

So, you add a Header Enricher before first HTTP Outbound Gateway. 
After this gateway you rearange your message to place that header back into a payload and do something with a session id. (Header I guess?). And only after that your have another HTTP Outbound Gateway for uploading your file.